# loopback3: issue with filter[where][property][eq]=string where string first digit is numerical

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I've been struggling with this.

I had this type of query working fine

```
/Accounts/:id/teams
```

Where

```
Account.teams: hasMany Team fk:ownerId
Team.owner: belongsTo Account fk: ownerId
```

in Account.json

```
"properties": {
  "id": {
    "type": "string",
    "id": true,
    "defaultFn": "guid"
  },
```

until the first letter of :id happened to be a numerical... because I used a table of accounts from a keystonejs app. Can't generated guid have a numerical as first digit?

having same issue with filters, the only way around it I found was to use where: {ownerId: { regexp: "/^5dsd43$/" }

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by getting rid of imported keystonejs accounts.id (it was a hexadecimal!)

Sorry for the noise